# Opencart Module CSS Adjustment

Tags: css, module, opencart

Please, I need help adjusting the opencart CSS to allow a module fit in firmly on this site am working on (http://www.cedamart.com), it pushes down the Featured Products module instead of the two being together on the same row.

I will appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: I am guessing you are referring to the "Order Invoice" block. Firstly you need to apply `float:left` to that block. You will then need to apply a fixed width to allow it to sit next to the fixed width "Feature Products" block. The "Order Invoice" block width will need to be adjusted for each breakpoint. Give this a try and then if you are still having issues, supply an example of the code so we can help.

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response. The issue is that, there's no specific code for the "Order Invoice" block in the stylesheet. The class namely ".box" also works for other blocks. I don't mind PMing you my admin login to help me fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Please, I need help adjusting the "Order Invoice" module to fit in firmly on the same row with the Featured Products module on this site am working on (http://www.cedamart.com). It pushes down the Featured Products module. I want to ask if the adjustment has to be done in the module's code or in the theme's stylesheet? Your kind help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can solve this problem by adding CSS to your themes stylesheet. Sadly this site is not for people to come up with code for you, but to respond to specific questions related to specific code. However I will try and point you in the right direction. To target the "Order Invoice" div you need to do `.home_page #content > div:first-child`. You can then relate to my previous comment to apply the styles you need.

Comment: @WizardCoder, I am so grateful for your support. Your "float:left" advise worked. i used it in the module's code. Thanks so much. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Follow the below steps -

Step 1.

Go to CSS file below -

```
http://www.cedamart.com/catalog/view/theme/bt_gomarket/stylesheet/skeleton.css
```

Step 2.

Search for ".container .nineteen.columns" , now change its width from 930px to 870px or 70%.

Hope it will help.

Feel free to discuss in case of any query or issue.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. However, I've resolved it by editing the module's code by adding a float:left styling. Thank you for your contribution.